# Отправить фото без сжатия telebot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, png, jpeg

Есть вот такой код:

```py
def send_skin(message, skin_id: int):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('db.sqlite3')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""SELECT name, path,  description, author FROM skins WHERE id = ?""", (skin_id,))
    skin = cursor.fetchone()
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
    photo = open(f'skins/{skin[1]}', 'rb')
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo, caption=f'Name: {skin[0]}\nDescription: {skin[2]}\nAuthor: {skin[3]}')
```

Он отправляет .png картинку пользователю, НО пользователь получает .jpeg, что очень плохо так как прозрачный фон исчезает. Можно ли как-то отправлять пользователю фото в .png? Пробовал через send_document. Все ок и телега видит его как пнг, но вот скачивается он в неизвестном формате, что опять таки плохо. Перепробовал все, в гугле пусто на эту тему. Очень не хочу подключать файлообменники и архивацию этого всего чтобы отправить через send_document(так все работает, но это и лишняя нагрузка, и трата времени пользователя)

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("photos/photo.jpg", "rb") as file:
    bot.send_document(message.chat.id, document=file)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]